# How much is a bus from Buenos Aires to Rio de Janeiro?

Tags: buses, argentina, buenos-aires, rio-de-janeiro

I'm looking to get a feeling for the bus prices for the trip **Buenos Aires to Rio de Janeiro.**
[Plataforma10.com](http://plataforma10.com) gives me a price of AR$ 2350,00 (~271 US$) with Crucero del Norte, which I find a bit high.

I've read other people saying it's about 100 US$, but haven't found official sources (bus company websites?).

One way flights are about 230 US$ (if you book in advance), which made me think to go for a flight instead.

Comment: Note that if you take advantage of the unofficial "blue peso" exchange rate, then AR$ 2350 is around 190 US$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Buenos-Aires/Rio-de-Janeiro) quotes 1100 pesos (127USD) as the minimum, and links to the bus company website. So I guess it depends on the day of travel / purchase.